# Rails: Change value of a ID in the view set by current_user.id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application.html.erb, there is a hidden input field with id=current_user.id, so in this case is like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<%= current_user.id %>">
```

There is a way to change this id for the next request? So when I reload the page I get a number choosed by me, and not current_user.id.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use jquery or js for chaging the value of user_id. try something like this `$("#user_id").val(2)` , `$("#user_id").val(this_id_you_want_to_change)`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes but in this case, I reload the page and then in the browser js console I change the id. This Is ok, but I need something, if is possible, that change ID during the page reload, and not after page loading... Thank you

Comment: You can write <script>  inside the <head> </head> section, it will execute before page load.

Comment: @rod, you really should tell us more... why should it once hold the user_id and the next time some random number?

Comment: Lets assume I am a normal user without access to app development. Is it possibile to change this value?

Comment: Yes, the user can see and change anything in the document. Including hidden inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In every request if you want set or change set the params and load it.

```
<input type="hidden" id="user_id" value="<%= params[:id] || current_user.id %>">
```

and set id params whenever you want to change.

Comment: Thank you very much. Lets assume I am a normal user without access to app development. Is it possibile to change this value?

Comment: Yes, just add id value in url params like example.com?id=value it get change.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var id = $("#user_id").val();
    var originalInput = $('[id="user_id"]');
    var input = $('<input />', {
        'id':'user_id_2',
        'type': 'text',
        'value': 2
    });
    $(originalInput).replaceWith(input);
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Lets assume I am a normal user without access to app development. Is it possibile to change this value?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe LocalStorage can help you.

```
localStorage.setItem('choosed_user_id', id)
```

after reload

```
if (!!localStorage.getItem('choosed_user_id', id)) set new id
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Lets assume I am a normal user without access to app development. Is it possibile to change this value?

Comment: yes user can change localStorage from dev console or from source in hidden input.
If you want to restrict/validate changes for this value you need to do this logic in backend